# Solving “Edge IP restricted- Error code 1034” for cloudflare owned domains and AWS NLBs

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, cloudflare, aws-nlb

Hello everyone :slight_smile: .

I have a POS device where my application sends requests to my backend. But recently, I’ve been seeing sporadic errors reported in crashlytics as follows:

```
Received a 403 error. Data returned as a String was: <!DOCTYPE html>........<head> <title>Edge IP Restricted | api.myapp.com | Cloudflare</title>....properties:{errorCode:1034,helpful:a,version:1}}
```

I have read the following solutions:

- https://community.cloudflare.com/t/fixing-error-1034-edge-ip-restricted/348153
- https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/troubleshooting/cloudflare-errors/troubleshooting-cloudflare-1xxx-errors/#error-1034-edge-ip-restricted

But I cannot understand how to implement them, because:

- Our domain is cloudflare-owned, and all subdomains are managed in cloudflare.
- The subdomain has a CNAME record pointing to AWS NLB public endpoint, the record is “proxied” (yellow icon enabled)
- The said POS device is in a different network itself, out of our control at this point.

Can anyone please help fix this issue?

Thank you.